# Unable to unpack a malware sample

Tags: malware

I'm trying to unpack malware packed with ConfuserEx 1.0.0 and I can't seem to get it to work. Each time I remove the anti-tamper the whole file gets corrupted.

I tried all possible tools that I found online, when that failed I tried to do so manually using some tutorials I found online, I always end up destroying the executable in the first stage of the unpacking. I'm using dnspy for this sample.
each time I attempt to locate the anti-tamper module, it ends up being the incorrect one and i end up destroying the executable..

What am I missing here? 
Does anyone have experience with unpacking the confuserex packer? 
Can you guys link me to some information I'm missing? or maybe explain how the ConfuserEx works?

I would appreciate help in understanding how to unpack it. I'll provide the sample here:

```
[WARNING THIS IS A LIVE MALWARE SAMPLE]
eagleepicsocks.com/jk/jkeq.exe
[WARNING THIS IS A LIVE MALWARE SAMPLE]
```

Comment: @forest please do not encourage cross-posting. Flag for migration, if necessary. As I agree this might get better answers there, I am closing this one.